# VNC Viewer - Toolbar not clickable

Tags: raspbian, vnc

I have VNC Viewer successfully running Raspbian, and everything is clickable except for the top bar (with terminal, menu, time, etc.). The first time I got VNC Viewer to run, everything was clickable, but the second time, it seems like the top part is deactivated. How can I get the top bar to be clickable?

Answer (score 1):

Solved it - I don't know why this happened, but I just used 'sudo apt-get remove tightvncserver' and reinstalled it. Then, the taskbar became clickable!

Comment: Did not work in my case. Identical problem. Tried sudo remove command. What is the restore command?

Comment: Wouldn't that be the same you wrote to install in the first place
sudo apt-get tightvncserver?

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.